# How to add current clicked element to an array in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have number as below

```
<div class="btn">
    <span class="num-items">1</span>
</div>
<div class="btn">
    <span class="num-items">2</span>
</div>
<div class="btn">
    <span class="num-items">3</span>
</div>
<div class="btn">
    <span class="num-items">4</span>
</div>
<div class="btn">
    <span class="num-items">5</span>
</div>
```

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var currentEl = [];
    $(this).toggleClass('bg_red');
    currentEl.push($(this));

    if(currentEl.length >=3){
        alert("You can pick only 3 item");
    }
})
```

I want to add this element to an array every time I clicked on number so that when array length greater or equal to 3, I can alert message.

Comment: `var currentEl = [];` just needs to be outside the click function for your code to work. you currently reset it to an empty array each time the .btn is clicked

Comment: Thank for your fast respond. This why I console.log, this give me empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a log, you will see that `currentEl` is reset to `[]` everytime you click, because you redeclare it on every function call

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var currentEl = [];
    $(this).toggleClass('bg_red');
    
    console.log(currentEl)
    
    currentEl.push($(this));

    if(currentEl.length >=3){
        alert("You can pick only 3 item");
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">
  <span class="num-items">1</span>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <span class="num-items">2</span>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <span class="num-items">3</span>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <span class="num-items">4</span>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <span class="num-items">5</span>
</div>
```

Move currentEl to the outer scope, things will work well, but a small suggestion to the logic, is to remember to check the length before add

```js
var currentEl = [];
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('bg_red');
    
    console.log('before add', currentEl)
    
    if(currentEl.length >=3){
        alert("You can pick only 3 item");
        return;
    }
    
    currentEl.push($(this).find('span').text());
    
    console.log('after add', currentEl)

    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">
  <span class="num-items">1</span>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <span class="num-items">2</span>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <span class="num-items">3</span>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <span class="num-items">4</span>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <span class="num-items">5</span>
</div>
```